# Lyrics with "lalalalala" or "nanananana"?

Tags: creative-writing, lyrics

Lyrics with "lalalalala" or "nanananana"? Is there any lyrics of a popular song where the "lalalalala" is written? I noticed a lot of lyrics, don't have them, but the singers sing them for some reason. Is there an example of the opposite? The more popular the song, the better.

Comment: Unsure whether this is on-topic here, as it's asking about existing works of literature.

Comment: I've always loved these. Try "She's Got the Look", "Na Na Hey Hey Kiss Him Goodbye", "Land of 1000 Dances", "Hey Jude" "Piano Man" or "Those Were the Days"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, "LaLaLaLa" are featured in songs such as Taylor Swift's "Monolog (La La La)" which she wrote for a 11/07/09 hosting gig of Saturday Night Live and performed during her Monolog segment for the episode that night.   While probably not the most prominent use of the sound, it's featured heavily enough in the song that it was given a nod in the title.  If we want a non-repetitive use of the La syllable, then the most prominent song to feature it is "Do-Re-Me" from *The Sound of Music* which teaches the Von Trappe Children the solfège musical notes, of which, "La" is only note to not get a memanic for it (La, A note that follows Sol (Sew)).

LaLaLa is probably the most common English use of "Non-lexical Vocables" in lyric composition, which is a fancy way of saying "musical non-sense words" and many genres notably use them, such as Scat, Jazz, Beat Boxing.  Wikipedia also makes a point that Disney songs frequently make prominent use of NLVs, listing 11 songs over Ten films where they are prominent features in the song, with 7 out of the 11 featuring them as part of the title of the song, (Heigh-Ho, Zip-A-Dee-Doo-Da, Bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo, Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, Chim Chim Cher-ee, Substitutiary Locomotion/Treguna Mekoides and Tracorum Satis Dee, Whistle Stop (Robin Hood, so named for the opening's use of the singer's whistling of the tune, also notable for having a second non-sense word in the "Oodalade"), and Whoop-de-Dooper Bounce (Tigger Movie)).   The three songs with heavy use are "I wanna be like you," which features two characters getting into a somewhat friendly Scat battle, "Everybody Wants to be a Cat", which is sung by a character named "Scat Cat" who earns his name, and "Trashin' the Camp" which the entire lyrics are NLV.  Other musical culture feature it regularly, such as Native American vocalizations, Yodeling, and Celtic music (The most famous example of the later is the Irish folk song "The Rocky Road to Dublin" prominently heard in the 2009 Sherlock Holmes during the boxing scene.  The final line in the chorus of the song is "Wak Fol Ro De Ra" which is Irish nonsense.

Of course, the undisputed best known user for the NVL will forever be NaNaNaNaNaNa BATMAN!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know....but it sounds suspiciously like the famous Christmas song 'Deck the hallways'.

[Lyrics](https://www.metrolyrics.com/deck-the-halls-lyrics-christmas-carols.html)

Comment: Ooof.  Can't believed I missed that one in my in depth discussion.

Comment: @hszmv, That Christmas song popped in my head when I saw this question. :)